# Difference in Google in-app purchase receipt for same product

Tags: android, in-app-billing

What could be the reason for occurring a difference in the receipt for the same product purchased via Google In-app
Below are the two receipts

```
{"orderId":"GPA.1362-4361-9609-92649","packageName":"com.packagename","productId":"3months_india_ren","purchaseTime":1482758243279,"purchaseState":0,"developerPayload":"3months_india_ren_PRODUCT","purchaseToken":"gccfdngnccchdahhmbkmkajk.AO-J1OyF6HMThthN08i3w0hjO08QqfeIm-atzQ5po-EqDskX3B1RLhj8rPXwBryvgx8syNuiffWajG7_whJj3w-W-ZeJxwlWdPBx-rCoGHlQQnN0DWiWseE","autoRenewing":true}
```

The above one is having a field autoRenewing and below receipt for the same product doesn't have this.

```
{"orderId":"GPA.8155-9137-6811-46978","packageName":"com.packagename","productId":"3months_india_ren","purchaseTime":1480776593073,"purchaseState":0,"developerPayload":"3months_india_ren_PRODUCT","purchaseToken":"zhazithmsdfnegmtdunskebo.loJtI2JUQ8B9vK234hcLm4X5D3cZi9obfYTQdEcxJWVznFTm6fDnvTwRZ4gszzl6SQHS2GhAGJmPxO6ZnvObDa8aatgCmNRqk0vHnsLz1mXps7i9hncAmWRUvqGX3Uq8oihCVu5qrQ"}
```

Comment: Check the **Table 4** of [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html)

Comment: Have already done the same but it does mention about the possible values and states. The response itself doesn't possess the "autoRenew" field.